# PhpMyAdmin Error #1055 Message

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm getting this message everytime I click on the Databases tab up top. Clicking on the error message's Edit link takes me to the SQL Queries section where it shows the SQL query that's listed on the error message. I can't get rid of the query; it just comes back after I try to delete it. This is my very first go at phpmyadmin/MySQL by the way.

Clicking on the **Databases** tab:
[image: Clicking on the **Databases** tab:]

Clicking on **Edit** in the error popup takes me here:
[image: Clicking on Edit in the error popup takes me here:]

Comment: You need a full group by. You have 2 non agg columns and you are grouping by 1

Comment: I don't know what that means! I'm trying to get this set up in order to learn phpmyadmin, and I copy/pasted the code from the link, but I get another error: http://imgur.com/a/rLdrs

Also, it looks like it resets back to the old code whenever I restart phpmyadmin. How can I save it?

Comment: Please join me in [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) chat and ping me with a @ sign like @Drew . And I will try to explain it as it may take some time